# splice() not working on correctly

Tags: javascript, arrays, cookies, splice

I am setting a cookie for each navigation container that is clicked on.

It sets an array that is joined and set the cookie value.
if its clicked again then its removed from the array.

It somehow buggy.

It only splices after clicking on other elements. and then it behaves weird.

It might be that `splice` is not the correct method

```
var navLinkToOpen;
var setNavCookie = function(value){
var isSet = false;
var checkCookies = checkNavCookie()
  setCookieHelper = checkCookies? checkCookies.split(","): [];
  for(i in setCookieHelper){
    if(value == setCookieHelper[i]){
       setCookieHelper.splice(value,1);
       isSet = true;
}
}
if(!isSet){setCookieHelper.push(value)}
setCookieHelper.join(",")
 document.cookie = "navLinkToOpen"+"="+setCookieHelper;
}


var checkNavCookie = function(){
var allCookies = document.cookie.split( ';' );
for (i = 0; i < allCookies.length; i++ ){
 temp = allCookies[i].split("=")
 if(temp[0].match("navLinkToOpen")){
  var getValue = temp[1]
  }
 }
return getValue || false
}



$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#LeftNav li").has("b").addClass("navHeader").not(":first").siblings("li").hide()
  $(".navHeader").click(function(){
$(this).toggleClass("collapsed").nextUntil("li:has('b')").slideToggle(300);
setNavCookie($('.navHeader').index($(this)))
return false
  }) 

var testCookies = checkNavCookie();
 if(testCookies){
finalArrayValue = testCookies.split(",")
for(i in finalArrayValue){
 $(".navHeader").eq(finalArrayValue[i]).toggleClass("collapsed").nextUntil(".navHeader").slideToggle   (0);
}

}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for(i in setCookieHelper){
    if(value == setCookieHelper[i]){
```

reads as:

```
for element in setCookieHelper
```

this element may not be an int and that causes your splice to fail, Also you must check if the element is contains the position where you want to splice then you must check if it's value is within the setCookieHelper lenght before you try to splice.

if you want to splice at a given position you should use a for:

```
for(i=0;i<setCookieHelper.lenght;i++){
     if(value == setCookieHelper[i]){
         setCookieHelper.splice(i,1);
         isSet = true;
     }
}
```

splice expects an index where to begin "splicing" and the amount of "spliced" elements.

Comment: thanks, i hear what you are saying...  Maybe i am not using the correct method `splice()`. what i want is to just need to remove that number that is found.

Comment: yeah than this is what you want :) just  replace it for a normal for i fixed the last for to be exactly what you need :)